# I've trying to convert list to tuples to customized list to dictionaries. I'm trying to divide pack owner, submitter and consumer

Tags: python, dictionary

I've trying to convert list to tuples to customized list to dictionaries. I'm trying to divide pack owner, submitter and consumer. Please check the below expected output.

```
lst = [('name1', 'email1','id1','new1',11,'1','po'),
       ('name2', 'email2','id2','new2',12,'2','sub'),
       ('name3', 'email3','id3','new3',13,'3','sub'),
       ('name4', 'email4','id4','new4',14,'4','po'),
       ('name5', 'email5','id5','new5',15,'5','cons')]
```

I've tried using below code but unable to get the expected output

```
def lst_of_dict()
    res = [{"name":each[0], "email":each[1], "psid":each[2} for each in lst]

return jsonify({"add_sub":res})
```

I'm trying to get below output

```
{
"add_sub":{
"sub":[{"id":"id2","name":"name2","email":"email2"},{"id":"id3","name":"name3","email":"email3"}],
"po":[{"id":"id1","name":"name1","email":"email1"},{"id":"id4","name":"name4","email":"email4"}],
"consumer":[{"id":"id5","name":"name5","email":"email5"}]},}
```

I'm new to python please suggest me to change the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to the rescue:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [('name1', 'email1', 'psid1', 'new1', 11, '1', 'pack owner'),
       ('name2', 'email2', 'psid2', 'new2', 12, '2', 'submitter'),
       ('name3', 'email3', 'psid3', 'new3', 13, '3', 'submitter'),
       ('name4', 'email4', 'psid4', 'new4', 14, '4', 'pack owner'),
       ('name5', 'email5', 'psid5', 'new5', 15, '5', 'consumer')]

by_role = defaultdict(list)

for name, email, psid, new, id1, id2, role_name in lst:
    by_role[role_name].append({"name": name, "email": email, "psid": psid})

print({"add_sub": dict(by_role)})
```

prints out

```
{'add_sub': 
  {'pack owner': [{'name': 'name1', 'email': 'email1', 'psid': 'psid1'}, {'name': 'name4', 'email': 'email4', 'psid': 'psid4'}],
   'submitter': [{'name': 'name2', 'email': 'email2', 'psid': 'psid2'}, {'name': 'name3', 'email': 'email3', 'psid': 'psid3'}],
   'consumer': [{'name': 'name5', 'email': 'email5', 'psid': 'psid5'}]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
res = {"add_sub":{}}
for name, mail, psid, *_, role_name in lst:
    res['add_sub'].setdefault(role_name, []).append({"name":name, "email":mail, "psid":psid})
```

**Output:**

```
{'add_sub': 
  {'consumer': [{'email': 'email5', 'name': 'name5', 'psid': 'psid5'}],
  'pack owner': [{'email': 'email1', 'name': 'name1', 'psid': 'psid1'},
                 {'email': 'email4', 'name': 'name4', 'psid': 'psid4'}],
  'submitter': [{'email': 'email2', 'name': 'name2', 'psid': 'psid2'},
                {'email': 'email3', 'name': 'name3', 'psid': 'psid3'}]}}
```